# How to run python script with third party libraries on computer without python?

Tags: python, windows

I am doing coursework and one of the important requirements is to create a `.bat` file for scripts. The bat file should run the script. I took this step until one thought struck me.

Code .bat file:

```
@echo off
py -u "Task_1.py"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

In my code, I use many third-party libraries, including for creating an interface. Let's assume that this script will run on a computer without python. Is it possible to somehow write a `.bat` file that would check for the presence of python and third-party libraries, and in their absence would download them? Has anyone done something similar, could you suggest how this can be implemented?

Comment: Are you able to create a powershell script, which the batch file also executes - you could have it install python

Answer (score 0):

You could have the .bat file run a python environment you make and pip install dependencies, would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/14926725) answer says that curl comes with Windows version 10 or newer. Therefore I would just curl the installer:

```
curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1-amd64.exe
```

now run it with /quit as by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056265/14926725) answer:

```
.\python-3.10.1-amd64.exe /quiet
```

Then you can install pip as suggested as an alternative method from the [official pip website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/):

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now you can use pip install to get whatever libraries you might need:

```
pip install numpy
```

*Note: I have not been able to test this on my Windows so use with caution*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to redirect `curl` output to a file or use `-o` option

Answer (score 0):

I found a post to check if python is installed or not ([How do I test if Python is installed on Windows (10), and run an exe to install it if its not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715476/how-do-i-test-if-python-is-installed-on-windows-10-and-run-an-exe-to-install)). It explains it quite well.
For the modules I would suggest using `pip` and installing the required modules by a requirements file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your `.bat` script, you can first run `py --version` and check the return code of the command to see if Windows could find `py`.

If it couldn't:

- Download a Python installer. I don't know which utility is supposed to do that on Windows, but it should look similar to this (`wget` on Linux, saves the installer as `python-installer.exe`):

  ```
  wget -O python-installer.exe https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1-amd64.exe
  ```
- Then launch it and let the user go through the installation:

  ```
  ./python-installer.exe
  ```

Then, execute `pip install --user your libs` to install the libaries if needed.

Then, run your Python script.